# How to get int from Tuple<char[], int>[] in f#

Tags: .net, f#

I have a `(char [] * int) []` in F#.  I'd like to extract the integers into an `int[]`.
I have a wonderful, non-functional version as thus.

```
let temp = new List<int>() 
for i in population do 
    temp.Add(snd i)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a `System.Generic.List<int>` you can do:

```
let temp = ResizeArray (population |> Seq.map snd)
```

if you want an F# list you can do:

```
let temp = population |> List.map snd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in F# interactive to extract second part of each tuple into a new Array:

```
[|([|'a'; 'b'|], 123);([|'c'|], 456)|] |> Array.map snd;;
```

note that snd is a short-hand for Tuple.Second

Here's a detailed version:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.30110.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> let pascalString0 = ([||], 0)
let pascalString1 = ([|'c'|], 1)
let pascalString2 = ([|'a'; 'b'|], 2)
let pascalStrings = [|pascalString0; pascalString1; pascalString2|]
let result = pascalStrings|> Array.map snd ;;

val pascalString0 : 'a [] * int
val pascalString1 : char [] * int = ([|'c'|], 1)
val pascalString2 : char [] * int = ([|'a'; 'b'|], 2)
val pascalStrings : (char [] * int) [] =
  [|([||], 0); ([|'c'|], 1); ([|'a'; 'b'|], 2)|]
val result : int [] = [|0; 1; 2|]

>
```